# Redirect to dynamic page after sign in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a multi tenant website with login via Azure AD implemented. As of now, I have setup the `redirecturi` to a specific page and added that page to the list of reply urls.

My question is how can I navigate to a page which is not in the reply urls after login?

I am using ASP.NET core with OpenID Connect.

Example flow:

User navigates to `http://{domain}/orders/orderid` where order id is dynamic. The behavior I want is that the user should be taken to the (Azure AD) login menu and after entering the credentials, user should be redirected to the same page i.e. `http://{domain}/orders/orderid`.

As of now, what I have is user is redirected to the Azure AD login menu, but after entering the credentials, user is taken to a predefined page ('profile') which is in the list of reply urls.

Sample code:

```cs
public IActionResult LogIn()
{
   if ( !User.IsAuthenticated() )
   {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/profile" },OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   }
   else
   {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Home" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly add `[Authorize]` on your orders controller . If user is not authenticated , he will be redirected to Azure AD login page .

Then use `new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }` . After user is authenticated , he will be redirected to the original page (http://{domain}/orders/orderid)

Comment: Is it possible to do without the [Authorize] attribute, since I want the Azure AD login page to appear only if a login is required. (Some orders should be visible to everyone).Also, I may need to make the call through javascript.